# How to filter Home Directory location from net user accounts?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

There is the command `net user` to list all **User Accounts**.
The output of the command is something like this:

```
Administrator            Guest                    asroot
1psaadm                  2satish                  3shyam                    
4sushil                  5sysuser_8               6sysuser_b                
tcuser                   test1                    test11 
...
```

If I run this **command**

```
net user shyam
```

the **output** is:

```
Workstations allowed         All
Logon script                 
User profile                 
Home directory               C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com
Last logon                   6/5/2021 4:57:17 AM

Logon hours allowed          All
```

I want only the `Home Directory` path from all `user accounts`. So I want **only this path** `C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com` from all user accounts.

I tried to get the wanted data with this command, but there is **no output**.

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %a in ('wmic UserAccount get Name') do net user %a | findstr /c:"Home directory"
```

How can I get the list of all paths of all user accounts?

**Note:** If there is no `Home directory` path in your cmd then you can try to list:

```
Logon hours allowed      ALL
```

Comment: Out of interest, is the output from the following any use to you: `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe NetLogin Get Caption,HomeDirectory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of **WMIC** is always a Unicode output with encoding [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-16) LE (little endian) with [BOM](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) (byte order mark) which is a problem in this case because of the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` is designed for processing text data with a [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) using just one byte per character. **CMD** interprets the UTF-16 LE encoded line ending with the hexadecimal byte values `0D 00 0A 00` (carriage return + line-feed) wrong as `0D 0D 0A` and for that reason each line processed further from captured output has a carriage return at end after removing the line ending `0D 0A`.

There is one more problem with the command line:

```
wmic UserAccount get Name
```

**WMIC** appends on all lines trailing spaces so that every output line has the same number of characters. That is problematic as a user name can contain also one or more spaces and for that reason the default string delimiters normal space and horizontal tab cannot be used to remove the unwanted trailing spaces. The usage of `tokens=*` results in removing just all leading spaces/tabs, but the trailing spaces remain.

What happens on using the following command line?

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %a in ('wmic UserAccount get Name') do
```

There is assigned one user account name after the other to the specified loop variable `a` with trailing spaces and a carriage return at end and for that reason the next command fails to work as expected.

In a command prompt window can be used:

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1* delims==" %G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe USERACCOUNT GET Name /VALUE 2^>nul') do @for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ("%H") do @for /F "tokens=2*" %J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "%I" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /C:"Home directory"') do @echo Home directory for "%I" is: "%K"
```

In a batch file can be used:

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe USERACCOUNT GET Name /VALUE 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%%H") do for /F "tokens=2*" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "%%I" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /C:"Home directory"') do echo Home directory for "%%I" is: "%%K"
```

This long command line is used best in a batch file as posted above, but better readable is:

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe USERACCOUNT GET Name /VALUE 2^>nul') do (
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%%H") do (
        for /F "tokens=2*" %%J in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe user "%%I" 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /C:"Home directory"') do (
            echo Home directory for "%%I" is: "%%K"
        )
    )
)
```

The first command **FOR** with option `/F` and a string enclosed in `'` starts in background one more command process with option `/c` to execute **WMIC** with full qualified file name and its four arguments with redirection `2>nul` to redirect a possible error message from handle **STDERR** (standard error) to device **NUL**. So executed is in background with Windows being installed into `C:\Windows` the command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmic.exe USERACCOUNT GET Name /VALUE 2>nul
```

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `wmic` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**WMIC** uses in this case the [Win32_UserAccount class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-useraccount) as documented by Microsoft.

The output of **WMIC** with option `/VALUE` at end is different to the output without this option. The output is now for each user account name:

- two empty lines and
- a line with `Name=` and user account name appended **without** trailing spaces which is one reason for using option `/VALUE`.

There are output two more empty lines in this case at the end by **WMIC**.

**FOR** respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file waits for self-termination of started `cmd.exe` and then processes the captured text data which was output to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of the background command process.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores always empty lines. But the Unicode encoded output of **WMIC** is not correct processed unfortunately by `cmd.exe` and for that reason there are lines containing just a carriage return and lines starting with `Name=` and a user account name and an erroneous carriage return at the end. So it is not possible to process the captured output directly.

The usage of the options `skip=2 tokens=1* delims==` results in

- skipping the first two captured lines which are always empty lines,
- splitting each line up into two substrings with the equal sign as string delimiter existing always once after `Name` on the lines of interest with the account name,
- using the default end of line character `;` which is no problem here as the lines of interest start always with `Name`
- and getting assigned to specified loop variable `G` the carriage return on the wrong processed empty lines or `Name` on a line with a user account name and to next but one loop variable `H` according to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) either no string at all on the empty lines or the user account name with an unwanted carriage return at the end.

**NOTE:** A user account name beginning very unusual with one or more equal signs would not be correct processed by this code as all equal signs at beginning of the user account name would be removed by **FOR** too.

The second **FOR** again with option `/F` processes now just the string assigned to the loop variable `H`. So there is no string to process at all assigned to `H` for empty lines interpreted wrong as a line with a single carriage return and so the second **FOR** loop filters out the empty lines.

For the lines with the user account name the name with the unwanted carriage return at end assigned to loop variable `H` is processed by the the second **FOR** with removing the newline character carriage return and assigned the rest to the specified loop variable `I` which is the wanted user account name. The option `eol=|` is used here to avoid that an unusual name starting with one or more semicolons is ignored by second **FOR**. No user account name can contain a vertical bar as this is a character not allowed for file/folder names.

The third **FOR** loop once again with option `/F` runs in background again one more command process to execute **NET** with output redirected first to **FINDSTR** to filter out all lines except the line starting case-sensitive with `Home directory`. **NET** outputs the text data with a one byte per character encoding making it possible to filter the output with **FINDSTR** and processing the captured output by **FOR** more easily. The command executed in background is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\net.exe user "%%I" 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /C:"Home directory"
```

The third **FOR** has to process always only one line starting with `Home directory`, fifteen spaces for alignment and perhaps nothing more or the home directory path as defined for the user account. There is used the option `tokens=2*` to split up the line using default space/tab as line delimiters to get assigned the word `directory` to the specified loop variable `J` and the entire home directory path to next but one loop variable `K` which can contain also one or more spaces or being an empty string as on my Windows computer for all accounts.

The third **FOR** executes finally the command **ECHO** to output the message with the user account name as determined by the second **FOR** and the home directory path as determined by third **FOR** if there is a home directory path at all.

---

[Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) suggested to use **WMIC** with the [Win32_NetworkLoginProfile class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkloginprofile) by using:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe NetLogin Get Caption,HomeDirectory
```

That class has account name and home directory path as members and so the wanted data can be get directly with **WMIC**.

The list of names is different between the two classes as it can be seen on running both **WMIC** commands in a command prompt window and reading the description for property **Name** of both classes carefully whereby the string of property `Caption` of `Win32_NetworkLoginProfile` class differs also from string of property `Name` of this class. The string of `Caption` is just the account name for a real user account while the string of `Name` is **ComputerName\AccountName** for a local account or **Domain\AccountName** for a domain account.

However, it is perhaps possible to use the data of this class with the following code in a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe NETLOGIN GET Caption^,HomeDirectory /VALUE 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%G" == "Caption" (
        set "AccountName="
        for /F "eol=| tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%I in ("%%H") do if "%%J" == "" set "AccountName=%%I"
    ) else if "%%G" == "HomeDirectory" (
        set "HomeDirectory="
        for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%%H") do set "HomeDirectory=%%"
        if defined AccountName (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo Home directory for "!AccountName!" is: "!HomeDirectory!"
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

There is again the option `/VALUE` as otherwise there would be again trailing spaces after home directory path if there is a home directory path output at all for an account which is not the case on my Windows computer.

The code is written to ignore the accounts containing in `Caption` a backslash like `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` and `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` which are most likely not of interest at all. Well, it would be also possible to use `if not "%%I" == "NT AUTHORITY"` instead of `if "%%J" == ""` to filter out the accounts of no interest as not being real user accounts.

The advantage of this solution is that there is started `cmd.exe` only once in background to run `wmic.exe` and get all the data of interest. So this solution is faster.

---

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `net /?`
- `net user /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic netlogin /?`
- `wmic netlogin get /?`
- `wmic useraccount /?`
- `wmic useraccount get /?`